# WhatsApp link is not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, whatsapp

There is a task to open whatsApp link to mobile devices with contact's number buyout written.

Link example:

```
<a href="intent://send/0930201003#Intent;
         scheme=smsto;
         package=com.whatsapp;
         action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end" 
         target="_blanc" >whatsapp</a>
```

This only works on Android devices. This does not work for iPhone devices, apparently because IOS adds the link like

`<a href="whatsapp://send?abid=phoneNumber" target="_blank"> whatsapp </a>`

This only opens a list of chat, not contacts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe just a typo in the question, but you have `target="_blanc"` in your first link.

Comment: the first link he says works, whether there's a typo i dont think that has anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

**For iOS:**

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=123456">WhatsApp</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the link does not work